# Get quote item id after product added to cart in observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, quoteitem

I am working on a custom module where a single product of a certain sku (say `fixed-product`) will be added to cart multiple times, but with different custom options programmatically. I also need to store it's `item_id` in another custom table for later use.

I managed to display the different products as separate entities on the cart (instead of just adding the quantity) by rewriting the `Codilar\ProfServices\Model\Rewrite\CartItem::representProduct()` method to `return false` if the conditions are met.

But I cannot obtain the `item_id` of the item once it's added to cart. I tried the following events

`checkout_cart_product_add_after` and `sales_quote_item_set_product`

but in the observer when I do `$this->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getItemId()` it always returns `NULL`

How do I get the `item_id` of an item added to cart in the observer?

Answer (score 3):

For checkout_cart_add_product_complete event

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class CheckoutCartAddProductCompleteObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getDataByKey('product');

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
        $item = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);

        $itemId = $item->getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create **events.xml** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="get_quote" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Getquote" />
    </event>

</config>
```

Create **Getquote.php** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Getquote.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Getquote implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {   
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $quoteItems = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Dinesh yadav, I am getting quoteid as empty, here is my question,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/quote-id-is-empty-when-inserting-multiple-records-into-cart-in-magento2

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Quote object itself if you do a `$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()` right?

If so, you may try the following:

```
$items = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems(); // get only visible items
$maxId = 0;
foreach ($items as $item){
  if ($item->getId() > $maxId) {
     $maxId = $item->getId();
  }
}
$lastItemId = $maxId;
```

This should get you the last item ID that was added in, for instance, `checkout_cart_product_add_after`.

But it may be that the cart is not yet saved at `checkout_cart_product_add_after` (then your last added item will not yet have an item id) so maybe you should check if there is a `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`. That one should work.